# Error creating bean because it's an interface?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Basically I have two beans implementing the same interface. One is for profile "default" and another "integration".

```
public interface SomeClientIfc { ... }

@Component
@Profile(value={"functional", "integration"})
public class StubSomeNIOClient implements SomeClientIfc {...}

public class SomeNIOClient implements SomeClientIfc {...}

@Configuration
@Profile("default")
public class SomeClientConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public SomeClientIfc someClient() {
      ...
    SomeNIOClient someClient = new SomeNIOClient(numberOfParititions, controllerHosts, maxBufferReadSize,
        connectionPoolSize);
    return someClient;
  }
}
```

In prod code it's

```
   @Autowired
   public SomeUserResolver(..., SomeClientIfc someClient) {...}
```

So far so good and I did see the stub bean is called in an integration test. Then I want to inject some test data into the stub bean in my integration test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/configProperties.xml", "/integrationTests.xml", ...})
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
public class SomeTestBase {
  @Autowired
  private SomeClientIfc someClientIfc;
}
```

However, when running the test I got error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someClientIfc': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.audiencescience.some.client.SomeClientIfc]: Specified class is an interface
```

I even tried to replace SomeClientIfc with StubSomeNIOClient but still get the same message, even though StubSomeNIOClient is not an interface.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Spring and this is part of our production code. I don't know how to extract them out.

Comment: I've seen this problem when I used `@ContextConfiguration` with an interface on the `classes` attribute.  I meant to use a Java config class.  Since this is XML config, I'd check to see if one of the bean definitions is mistakenly trying to instantiate using only the interface and not a class.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `Qualifier` annotation along with the `Autowired` one to specify which bean must be instantiated:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("my-bean")
```

Comment: They are achieving this through `@Profile` already. Only one of the beans above will be active during their integration test. In any case, this doesn't explain why Spring is trying to instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's trying to inject the SomeClientIfc is because you called the variable 'someClientIfc'.

In the integration environment you have all 3 classes initialized: SomeClientIfc, StubSomeNIOClient, and SomeNIOClient. This creates a confusion for spring, luckily there are ways to resolve that confusion.

One way is as mentioned above by Little Santi, another way is to name your variable 'stubSomeNIOClient' see code below

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/configProperties.xml", "/integrationTests.xml", ...})
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
public class SomeTestBase {
  @Autowired
  private SomeClientIfc stubSomeNIOClient;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't _yet_ on the injection. The current failure OP is asking about is `Failed to instantiate [com.audiencescience.some.client.SomeClientIfc]`. Your answer does not explain why Spring is trying to instantiate that type.